# THREE.js OBB Implementation

Tags: javascript, three.js, bounding-box, convex-hull, aabb

I was able to use [Yuka_OBB](https://github.com/Mugen87/yuka/blob/844b2581d29de0105336be80eb2fe4cc8dca4ede/src/math/OBB.js#L409-L597) implementation to generate oriented bounding box. I have some questions regarding the obtained results:

**Bed (AABB)**

[image: bed_aabb]

**Bed (OBB)**

[image: bed_obb]

**Wall (AABB)**

[image: wall_aabb]

**Wall (OBB)**

[image: wall_obb]

**Question:**
What type of OBB is generated here from one of the following types:

1. modal
2. up/gravity aligned
3. arbitrarily oriented in 3D space
4. semantically oriented with front

**Question:**

While, Bed (OBB) seems properly aligned, I want to understand what's going on with Wall (OBB)? Can I do better to improve the orientation of box around wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is arbitrarily oriented in 3D space.

If it is the best-fit box, you can't improve it without getting a larger OBB. Read [gamma.cs.unc.edu/users/gottschalk/main.pdf](http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/users/gottschalk/main.pdf) to get a better understanding of OBBs

Comment: If it is the best-fit box, you can't improve it without getting a larger OBB.

Comment: I've never heard gravity-aligned OBBs, sorry.

Comment: @Rabbid76 TBH, I'm not sure what other information I should add to the answer. The OP should not ask multiple questions in one thread. I've just answered the first one.

Comment: The `three.js` forum is actually the better place for this type of question: https://discourse.threejs.org/

Comment: @Mugen87 I see. Duplicate?

Comment: Oh, indeed! That is a duplicated.

Comment: The OP should read http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/users/gottschalk/main.pdf to get a better understanding of OBBs.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the answer (BTW: I can only delete my own comments).